# CloudWatch metric for concurrent executions not working

Tags: concurrency, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-serverless

My AWS lambda function has CloudWatch dashboards for errors, invocations ,duration, throttles & concurrentexecutions. It is showing data for all metrics except concurrentexecutions for the same timeline. A 'No data available' is always displayed on its dashboard.

I have not set a 'Reserve Concurrency' for the function, so it is using the default account level concurrency limit of 1000 as I understand. 'Throttle' dashboard is reflecting '0' at all times when lambda invocations occurred which makes sense. but why 'concurrent executions' has 'no data available' I am not sure[image]

any suggestions as to what could be the problem ?

```
Resources:
MyLambdaDashboard:
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
Properties:
  DashboardName: !Ref DASHBOARDNAME
  DashboardBody: '{
  **<Other Metrics Dashboard>**
  ,
 {
 "type":"metric",
       "x":0,
       "y":14,
       "width":12,
       "height":6,
       "properties":{
         "view":"timeSeries",
         "stacked":false,
         "metrics":[
           ["AWS/Lambda", "ConcurrentExecutions", "FunctionName", "${FUNCTIONNAME}", {
             "period":60,
             "stat":"Sum"
           }]
         ],
         "region":"${AWSREGION}",
         "title":"Concurrent Executions",
         "yAxis":{
           "left":{
             "min":0
           }
         },
         "legend": {
             "position": "hidden"
         }
       }
     }
    ]
  }'
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your widget/metric configuration for it? You don't need to do anything to get concurrent executions to be reported, so I'm suspicious that the wrong time frame / aggregation is in use.

Comment: I have added the cloudformation code & dashboard image for 'concurrent executions' metric. note that we also have a 'throttle' dashboard

Comment: I fixed the problem. didn't realise that 'Concurrent Executions' metric is an account-level metric , not a Lambda level. Removing the "FunctionName" parameter from the above cloudformation template fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

'Concurrent Executions' metric is an account-level metric , not a Lambda level. Removing the "FunctionName" parameter from the above cloudformation template fixes the problem